# Resizing photos becomes slower, maybe because i am not closing stream all streams?

Tags: java, url, image-resizing, urlconnection, fileoutputstream

so i am trying to resize image that I download using this method, however, after resizing about 100 images, the program becomes super slow. I think its because I forgot to close a connection or something but I am pretty sure I closed all streams and connections. I do not know what is wrong and what is clogging up all my memory to make it run so slow that eventually the program is just suspended. Please help!

```
private String resizePhoto(String str, String leg_id, int size, String path) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    if (str == null || str.trim().equals(""))
        return "http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-default-avatar.png";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(str);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        InputStream stream = url.openStream();
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(stream);
        BufferedImage newImg = Scalr.resize(img, Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH, size, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);

        Iterator<ImageWriter> writerIt = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");
        if (writerIt.hasNext() ) {
            ImageWriter writer = writerIt.next();
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(path + leg_id + ".jpg");
            ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(f);
            writer.setOutput(ios);
            ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
            writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            writeParam.setCompressionQuality(0.9f);
            writer.write(null, new IIOImage(newImg, null, null), writeParam);
            f.close();
            writer.dispose();
            ios.close();
        }

       stream.close();
       connection.disconnect();
       return path + leg_id + ".jpg";

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {e.printStackTrace();System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {};

    return "http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-default-avatar.png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible you're not cleaning up all your resources with that code.  You're swallowing `IOExceptions` without any messaging so you won't be able to easily see if that's happening.  I recommend using a `finally` block on your `try-catch` and include your `.close()`, `.disconnect()` and `.dispose()` calls there.  Make sure to check them for null first to protect against NPEs.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your `close()` method into a finally block so that if an exception is thrown they are still closed. For example

```
//Declare stream as null
FileOutputStream f = null
try
{ 
   //initialise stream
   f = new FileOutputStream(path + leg_id + ".jpg");
   // do your stuff
}
catch (//the exceptions you want to catch)
{
    //What ever you want to do with caught exceptions, you should always at least print statcktrace
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    if(f!= null)
        f.close();  // this might need its own try/catch also
}
```

Currently in your code you could get an IO exception and you just disregard it